# Python prints two backslash instead of one

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, backslash

My goal is to print a backslash in Python3. My input is

```
links22 = ['1',"n","nkf"]
treee = ['<img src={} \>'.format(i) for i in links22]
print(treee)
```

The output that I get is:

```
['<img src=1 \\>', '<img src=n \\>', '<img src=nkf \\>']
```

And when I try:

```
print("\\")
```

The output is:

```
\
```

I want to figure out why the first output is \ and in the second is .

Comment: It might also be helpful to compare `print("\\")` to `print(r"\\")`.

Answer (score 1):

The first `\` is escaping the second, since `\` is illegal. In the first example `\` is interpenetrate as escape to `>`

```
print("\\\\")
```

Will print `\\`

Answer (score 0):

The answer you can find here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=comment%20strings

```
\
```

Either escapes special characters (permitting you to match characters like '*', '?', and so forth), or signals a special sequence; special sequences are discussed below.

Most of the standard escapes supported by Python string literals are also accepted by the regular expression parser:

```
\a      \b      \f      \n
\N      \r      \t      \u
\U      \v      \x      \\
```