# Python3 prints two backslash

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, jupyter-notebook, backslash

My goal is to print a backslash in Python3. My input is

```
links22 = ['1',"n","nkf"]
treee = ['<img src={} \\>'.format(i) for i in links22]
print(treee)
```

The output that I get is:

```
['<img src=1 \\>', '<img src=n \\>', '<img src=nkf \\>']
```

The output that I want is:

```
['<img src=1 \>', '<img src=n \>', '<img src=nkf \>']
```

And when I try:

```
print("\\")
```

The output is:

```
\
```

I want to figure out why the first output is \ and in the second is .

Comment: Actually this is correct, if you print the results, there should only be one backslash.

Comment: \\ means you are escaping the literal `\\` character.

Comment: Please don't repost questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python prints two backslash instead of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639925/python-prints-two-backslash-instead-of-one)

Comment: Actually if you print your strings from the list - they will be printed with one slash only. e.g. `for item in treee: print(item)` will give you results that you expect

Comment: html tags end with `/` forward slash. If that's what your building.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are printing an array, not a string. If you print a string then this apply the escape character.

but a example of how do it would be:

```py
...
print(*treee)
# print(*treee, sep=",") # if you want custom separator
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform `print(treee)`, what you are seeing is an escaped representation of the backslash in each of the elements in the list.

If you do this instead:

```
for a_tree in treee:
    print(a_tree)
```

you will see the single backslash as expected.