# backslashes in strings

Tags: python

When printinga a string containing a backslash, I expect the backslash (`\`) to stay untouched.

```
test1 = "This is a \ test String?"
print(test1)
'This is a \\ test String?'

test2 = "This is a '\' test String?"
print(test2)
"This is a '' test String?"
```

What I expect is "`This is a \ test String!`" or "`This is a '\' test String!`" respectively. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you `print` them (or write them to a file) the \ is escaped.

Comment: The `.replace()` has NOTHING to do with this - if you just typed `test1` or `test2`, to display the `repr()` of the string value, you'd get exactly the same behavior of the backslash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python prints two backslash instead of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639925/python-prints-two-backslash-instead-of-one)

Comment: What helped was the answer mentioning raw string. The question you posted doesn't have that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues.

First case, you're getting the *representation* not the string value. that's a classic explained for instance here: [Python prints two backslash instead of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639925/python-prints-two-backslash-instead-of-one)

Second case, you're *escaping* the quote unwillingly. Use raw string prefix in all cases (specially treacherous with Windows hardcoded paths where `\test` becomes `<TAB>est`):

```
test2 = r"This is a '\' test String?"
```

In the first case, it "works" because `\`  doesn't escape anything (for a complete list of escape sequences, check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)), but I would not count too much on that in the general case. That raw prefix doesn't hurt either:

```
test1 = r"This is a \ test String?"
```

Comment: prints with 2 backslashes.

Comment: representation has 2 backslashes. try to `print` it. There are 2 problems as explained.

Comment: Doi - I just did that; I am blaming my tiredness on this mistake.

Comment: @Sadık I guess like `.replace("\\\\", "\\")`

Answer (score 1):

You should add an extra backslash in your code before the replace:

```
test2 = "This is a '\\' test String?"
test2.replace("?", "!")
"This is a '\' test String!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is actually doing what you expect - the confusion lies in the fact that you are using `str.__repr__` to display the content of the string. If you `print` it, it looks ok:

```
In [17]: test1 = "This is a \ test String?"

[18]: test1
Out[18]: 'This is a \\ test String?'

In [19]: print(test1)
This is a \ test String?
```

Python shows the string with a double backslash as a single backslash wouldn't be an acceptable representation (i.e. it would mean you are escaping the character after the backslash)